# Tag synonyms - which one should be the main tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There has been some discussion regarding tags with models, series, and manufacturers, and combinations.

*If* we make synonyms, what should we choose to be the main tag? The shorter one?

Example: [cisco-asa](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco-asa), [asa](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asa)

We will have some synonyms, otherwise some will separately appear again and again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most explanatory one; in this case, [cisco-asa](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco-asa) should be the main tag.

This avoids ambiguity if other products/ acronyms of ASA exist. Furthermore, this allows a *consistent* approach; e.g. we avoid the situation where [asa](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asa) is acceptable *unless* it's ambiguous in which case it should be [cisco-asa](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco-asa)... then we end up with *both* versions existing on the site.

Comment: Yes, the least ambiguous tag should be the main one.